# PHP get URL of page iframe is located on inside the iframe

Tags: php, url, iframe

I've been looking around on the web and I can't find a solution to my issue.

Lets say on the following page I have an iframe.

```
http://www.mysite.com/cakes.php - this is the url of the page the iframe is on
```

This is the iframe code on that page

```
<iframe src = "http://www.mysite.com/secret_frame.php"></iframe>
```

In the iframe (the file secret.php), how would I get the URL of the page the iframe is situated on, so in this case it would be http://www.mysite.com/cakes.php.

Thanks

Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iframed page, `secret_frame.php`, can access the parent-page including it through the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable.

As mentioned in @Sven's answer, you can't completely trust the Referrer sent to the page though. Directly from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: do you mean $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? I think you made a spelling mistake.

Comment: @Frank Oops, my mistake - you're correct; Updated my spelling error, thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1):

It would usually be in the referrer - but remember referrers cannot be trusted, they might be changed or missing alltogether.